# Is the derived area/length/xy values of a polygon/polyline layer in QGIS usable?

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, area, fields-attributes

I have a raster that is projected to a state plane CRS and I am adding polygon/polyline shapefiles that are projected to WGS84.  On the fly transformation is set to reproject to my raster CRS.  When I use the identify features tool to select a feature, under derived I can see the correct area/length measurements.  Is there a way to transfer that exact information into a new column(s) in the attributes by using the field calculator?

Comment: Do you have a specific use case for needing a duplicate field?

Comment: The data under derived is not viewable in the attributes and would like to be able to view that data on other platforms

Comment: Ok my bad. I don't use qgis everyday, see comment on answer. I am pretty sure qgis works like this too.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not sure about the right units of measurements, save a copy of the shapefile into the CRS of the raster.

That way you will get the correct values using the $area function in field calculator.

Note that identify tool and field calculators use different methods to calculate areas:
https://hub.qgis.org/issues/4252

```
Vector -> Geometry Tools -> Export/Add geometry columns
```

lets you choose if measurement of the new columns shall be in layer CRS, project CRS or ellipsodial (which the identify tool uses).

Answer (score 0):

Add a column of the type you desire to use.
Use field calculator,
My field = [area]
Not exact syntax.

Comment: So by using $area expression in the field calculator, the area is calculated based off of the layer's CRS (WGS84) which will yield either an unusable answer or 0.  I am wondering if there is a specific expression that will read the info that is under derived.

Comment: $area would work if you have a spatial database.  [area] is the existing area field.

Comment: You are saying that your layer is in WGS but the area field is in your desired units? I don't have qgis in front of me. But if I were in arcmap I would set the document projection to the units I want, and calculate the length or area using the document units. Possibly a check box

Comment: $area will return the area of the polygon in the layers units.